# Global Tag replace in text from a objet/array (Tag -> value) javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a piece of code to replace "Tags" by values in Strings
My concern is that it only changes the first Tag encountered if it exists several times :(

```
const replaceTagsToValue = (obj, chaine) => obj.reduce((f, s) => `${f}`.replace(Object.keys(s)[0], s[Object.keys(s)[0]]), chaine)

const Tags = [
    { "{info_1}": "One" },
    { "{info_2}": "Two" },
    { "{info_3}": "Three" }
    // etc etc...
]

let input = "{info_1}-{info_2}-{info_3} | {info_3}-{info_2}-{info_1}";
let output = replaceTagsToValue(Tags, input);
console.log(output);
```

**Result:**

```
One-Two-Three | {info_3}-{info_2}-{info_1}
```

**Want these result:**

```
One-Two-Three | Three-Two-One
```

I tested with the addition of a global regex approach, without success of course:

```
.replace(/Object.keys(s)[0]/g, s[Object.keys(s)[0]])
```

Do you have a solution ? see a more suitable and more generic or best practice solution?

Thank's !

Comment: Based on your logic in `replaceTagsToValue`, shouldn't your expected output be `One-Two-Three | Three-Two-One` ?

Comment: yes it's right, it's a error of manual writing ;) i make the change... thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you cannot use the literal notation (`/Object.keys(s)[0]/g`) to build a dynamic RegExp,
you need to use the constructor (`new RegExp(Object.keys(s)[0], 'g')`) instead:

```js
const replaceTagsToValue = (obj, inStr) => obj.reduce((f, s) => f.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(s)[0], 'g'), s[Object.keys(s)[0]]), inStr)

const Tags = [
  { '{info_1}': 'One' },
  { '{info_2}': 'Two' },
  { '{info_3}': 'Three' }
  // etc etc...
]

const input = '{info_1}-{info_2}-{info_3} | {info_3}-{info_2}-{info_1}'
const output = replaceTagsToValue(Tags, input)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Yes ! it work, u save my life ;)  it's difficult to get all the great syntax when you begin in a new langage.. Thank's a lot !